# DIVs with background-size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-image, background-size

I am having an issue with trying to make a fluid HTML page. (I wanted to take into account different sized resolutions, so I'm working with background images with widths of 1920px)

So I wanted to make a couple stacked divs, each with a background that gets resized via background-size.  However, I'm noticing that I can't get 100% or contain to work as the property value unless I also manually set the height of the div.  I can set it manually with a set px or %, but I feel like this isn't the best way to dynamically set the height of the div.

So I'm wondering if there's a better way to set the height of the div, so it's set to be the same height as the height of the image with the background-size property, so I don't get all the white space after the image, if the div is too tall.

I've got a live example here: https://jsfiddle.net/fcb1wcth/

```
#header {
background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/x5wEY56.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
height: 710px;
color: #ffffff;
}

For example, this first div above...  Since I'm working with a smaller screen, 710px is way too tall!  The background-size does its job, I just don't know how to set the height correctly, and using a property value of auto doesn't help it.
```

// I've never used background-size before, so maybe I'm doing this wrong, but I wanted to try and experiment with making a page that works with any resolution.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that better solution is to use a fixed `height` in combination with `background-size: cover`. Like this:

```
#header {
    background-size: cover;
    height: 400px;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/fcb1wcth/2/

Comment: Alright, excellent.  I think this is what I'll need to do (I was confused as to if I should use cover or contain).  I'll come up with a reasonable height for it.  And setting the fixed height won't be weird on 1080p monitors, right?

Comment: I don't think so. But you can always use media queries too :)

Comment: Actually you do not need to set a fixed height. You can use any positioned Layer that has width and height (i.e. also using percentages), and since you want a fluid Layout, you can also use the old "padding-bottom" trick to give your Layer a certain ratio (let's say 2:1) instead of a fixed height. Anyways, `background-size: cover` indeed seems to fit best here.

Answer (score 0):

in this example solve this issue.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Minimal-Full-Screen-Vertical-Slider-with-jQuery-Scroll-On-Scroll.html